# Power BI If statement

Tags: if-statement, powerbi-desktop

I have created four calculated columns that give True or False for a unique property ref in each row, based on the presence of a registered contact (CMS) on a list (Tele Open, Tele Closed, Written Open, Written Closed). I now need to assign a status to each property ref based on the combination of True False.

I am able to do this using a multiple nested IF AND statement in Excel but am confused about to do this in Power BI.

I haven't yet attempted to do this and need some advice on how to frame the statement, as I am not familiar enough with M Language.

'''
If -- ALL are FALSE = Not Yet Investigated

If -- Tele Open is TRUE = In Progress

If -- Tele Open is FALSE AND Tele Closed is FALSE AND Written Open AND/OR Written Closed is True = In Progress

If -- Tele Open is FALSE AND Tele Closed is TRUE = Closed
'''

The various combination of True False in the categories listed above will produce a Not Yet Investigated, In Progress or Closed status as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic syntax for a calculated column with an IF statement is

```
column = if [something] > 1 then [something] else [something else]
```

you can then nest statement using and and or

```
column = if [something] >= 1 and [something] <= 10
then "Low"
else if [something] >= 10 and [something] <= 20
then "medium"
else "high"
```

Hope that helps